# Positionning with flexbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I want to achieve this result using Flexbox :

- The red `div` is the `container`.
- The green `div` is a `navbar` menu that should be centered horizontally at the top.
- And then the titles of the page should be centered as the image displays.

PS : The red div's height is 100vh and width 100%.

[image]

The result of using this code displays both the green div and the titles at the center of the `container`.

```css
.header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 header">
      <div class="menu">
        <!-- navbar items -->
      </div>
      <h1>TITLE</h1>
      <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce a new element to wrap the content in the middle, set that to `flex-grow: 1` so that it consumes all of the available space left over from the parent, then center the contents of that element.

```css
.header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.header header {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header .menu {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 header">
      <div class="menu">
        header menu
      </div>
      <header>
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex-direction: column` on `header` and `align-items: center` for horizontal centering. And then just use margins to center `h1` and  `h2` vertically. Note that `.menu` will take space in `header` so h1 and h2 will be centered in space that is left, otherwise you need to use `position: absolute`

```css
div.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
div.menu {
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
}
.header h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.header h2 {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 header">
      <div class="menu">
        <!-- navbar items -->
      </div>
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```